# How to retrieve scalar value using JDBC?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, scalar

I'm now trying to call a sproc that returns scalar value which represents the inserted row's ID (which is varchar), how could this be achieved in JDBC?
What I'm now doing is let the DB sproc return result like this

```
select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

and in my code I use ResultSet

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
resultSet.next();
String productId = resultSet.getString(1);
```

Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Post code you tried so far. Also show table's schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's preferrable to retrieve generated IDs with JDBC as

```
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(insertStatement, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
    rs.next();
    String id = rs.getString(1);
```

Comment: Cool. But the problem is that I'm calling sproc, our company does not allow us to write sql ourselves thru JDBC